# Theano: how to efficiently undo/reverse max-pooling

Tags: python, optimization, neural-network, theano

I'm using Theano 0.7 to create a [convolutional neural net](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) which uses **[max-pooling](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#maxpooling)** (i.e. shrinking a matrix down by keeping only the local maxima).

In order to "undo" or "reverse" the max-pooling step, one method is to store the locations of the maxima as auxiliary data, then simply recreate the un-pooled data by making a big array of zeros and using those auxiliary locations to place the maxima in their appropriate locations.

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

minibatchsize = 2
numfilters = 3
numsamples = 4
upsampfactor = 5

# HERE is the function that I hope could be improved
def upsamplecode(encoded, auxpos):
    shp = encoded.shape
    upsampled = T.zeros((shp[0], shp[1], shp[2] * upsampfactor))
    for whichitem in range(minibatchsize):
        for whichfilt in range(numfilters):
            upsampled = T.set_subtensor(upsampled[whichitem, whichfilt, auxpos[whichitem, whichfilt, :]], encoded[whichitem, whichfilt, :])
    return upsampled


totalitems = minibatchsize * numfilters * numsamples

code = theano.shared(np.arange(totalitems).reshape((minibatchsize, numfilters, numsamples)))

auxpos = np.arange(totalitems).reshape((minibatchsize, numfilters, numsamples)) % upsampfactor  # arbitrary positions within a bin
auxpos += (np.arange(4) * 5).reshape((1,1,-1)) # shifted to the actual temporal bin location
auxpos = theano.shared(auxpos.astype(np.int))

print "code:"
print code.get_value()
print "locations:"
print auxpos.get_value()
get_upsampled = theano.function([], upsamplecode(code, auxpos))
print "the un-pooled data:"
print get_upsampled()
```

> *(By the way, in this case I have a 3D tensor, and it's only the third axis that gets max-pooled. People who work with image data might expect to see two dimensions getting max-pooled.)*

The output is:

```
code:
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]
locations:
[[[ 0  6 12 18]
  [ 4  5 11 17]
  [ 3  9 10 16]]

 [[ 2  8 14 15]
  [ 1  7 13 19]
  [ 0  6 12 18]]]
the un-pooled data:
[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   2.   0.
     0.   0.   0.   0.   3.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   4.   5.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   6.   0.   0.
     0.   0.   0.   7.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   8.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   9.  10.   0.   0.   0.
     0.   0.  11.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.  12.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  13.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    14.  15.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  16.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  17.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  18.
     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  19.]
  [ 20.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  21.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  22.   0.
     0.   0.   0.   0.  23.   0.]]]
```

This method **works** but it's a **bottleneck**, taking most of my computer's time (I think the set_subtensor calls might imply cpu<->gpu data copying). So: can this be implemented more efficiently?

I suspect there's a way to express this as a single `set_subtensor()` call which may be faster, but I don't see how to get the tensor indexing to broadcast properly.

---

**UPDATE:** I thought of a way of doing it in one call, by working on the flattened tensors:

```
def upsamplecode2(encoded, auxpos):
    shp = encoded.shape
    upsampled = T.zeros((shp[0], shp[1], shp[2] * upsampfactor))

    add_to_flattened_indices = theano.shared(np.array([ [[(y + z * numfilters) * numsamples * upsampfactor for x in range(numsamples)] for y in range(numfilters)] for z in range(minibatchsize)], dtype=theano.config.floatX).flatten(), name="add_to_flattened_indices")

    upsampled = T.set_subtensor(upsampled.flatten()[T.cast(auxpos.flatten() + add_to_flattened_indices, 'int32')], encoded.flatten()).reshape(upsampled.shape)

    return upsampled


get_upsampled2 = theano.function([], upsamplecode2(code, auxpos))
print "the un-pooled data v2:"
ups2 = get_upsampled2()
print ups2
```

However, this is still not good efficiency-wise because when I run this (added on to the end of the above script) I find out that the Cuda libraries can't currently do the integer index manipulation efficiently:

```
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: local_gpu_advanced_incsubtensor1
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1493, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/opt.py", line 952, in local_gpu_advanced_incsubtensor1
    gpu_y = gpu_from_host(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 507, in __call__
    node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/basic_ops.py", line 133, in make_node
    dtype=x.dtype)()])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py", line 69, in __init__
    (self.__class__.__name__, dtype, name))
TypeError: CudaNdarrayType only supports dtype float32 for now. Tried using dtype int64 for variable None
```

Comment: I suspect one could formulate this as one call to `set_subtensor` as you indicate. If your code were a self-contained example one could tinker around with it...

Comment: I added another way of doing it. But I am afraid that it will not solve your cuda problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is faster, but it may be a little more concise. See if it is useful for your case.

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

minibatchsize = 2
numfilters = 3
numsamples = 4
upsampfactor = 5

totalitems = minibatchsize * numfilters * numsamples

code = np.arange(totalitems).reshape((minibatchsize, numfilters, numsamples))

auxpos = np.arange(totalitems).reshape((minibatchsize, numfilters, numsamples)) % upsampfactor 
auxpos += (np.arange(4) * 5).reshape((1,1,-1))

# first in numpy
shp = code.shape
upsampled_np = np.zeros((shp[0], shp[1], shp[2] * upsampfactor))
upsampled_np[np.arange(shp[0]).reshape(-1, 1, 1), np.arange(shp[1]).reshape(1, -1, 1), auxpos] = code

print "numpy output:"
print upsampled_np

# now the same idea in theano
encoded = T.tensor3()
positions = T.tensor3(dtype='int64')
shp = encoded.shape
upsampled = T.zeros((shp[0], shp[1], shp[2] * upsampfactor))
upsampled = T.set_subtensor(upsampled[T.arange(shp[0]).reshape((-1, 1, 1)), T.arange(shp[1]).reshape((1, -1, 1)), positions], encoded)

print "theano output:"
print upsampled.eval({encoded: code, positions: auxpos})
```

Comment: This is indeed faster, thanks! On my GPU, as part of a larger program it leads to a speedup of 1.13x

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Does it change anything about the cuda error?

Comment: Yes: there's no cuda error when I use your version, unlike when I use my flattened approach. (The difference may simply be a mistake on my part in how to specify the casting.)

Comment: Stumbled over the post just now. Can it be that the CUDA error doesn't play a part in this because the data is 'int64'?
Since Theano only supports 32 bit on GPUs, this will lead to CPU execution of the function.